# How to group rows in a dataframe which are in a sequence?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

consider i have a data frame

| ID | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | item 1 |
| 10 | item 1 |
| 10 | item 1 |
| 9 | item 2 |
| 8 | item 3 |
| 8 | item 3 |
| 8 | item 3 |
| 8 | item 3 |
| 7 | item 4 |
| 6 | item 5 |
| 4 | item 6 |
| 4 | item 6 |
| 5 | item 7 |
| 5 | item 7 |

and i want to update a new column as result if the id column is in decreasing order i want something like this

| ID | Column B | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | item 1 | 1 |
| 10 | item 1 | 1 |
| 10 | item 1 | 1 |
| 9 | item 2 | 1 |
| 8 | item 3 | 1 |
| 8 | item 3 | 1 |
| 8 | item 3 | 1 |
| 8 | item 3 | 1 |
| 7 | item 4 | 1 |
| 6 | item 5 | 1 |
| 4 | item 6 | 2 |
| 4 | item 6 | 2 |
| 5 | item 7 | 2 |
| 5 | item 7 | 2 |

conditions are i should group the rows which are having the id columns with decreasing only by one value

i tried doing using the code
df["result"] = (df["X2"] > df["X2"].shift(1)).cumsum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) to compare the successive values, if >-1, this means we start a new group, with help of [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['result'] = df['ID'].diff().lt(-1).cumsum().add(1)
```

Output:

```
    ID Column B  result
0   10   item 1       1
1   10   item 1       1
2   10   item 1       1
3    9   item 2       1
4    8   item 3       1
5    8   item 3       1
6    8   item 3       1
7    8   item 3       1
8    7   item 4       1
9    6   item 5       1
10   4   item 6       2
11   4   item 6       2
12   5   item 7       2
13   5   item 7       2
```